# Flutter how to test which fields of a many fielded object are null?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I'm saving the users details to SharedPrefs in 3 places in my app, and it's going to lead to a lot of duplicate code.  So I want to roll a method into my Person class so I can call it from anywhere and save the users details there.

I have a var: user of Object Person, I've been fiddling with Keys and String to access it's fields, but always the same error:

> The getter 'attribute' isn't defined for the type 'Person'.  Try
>   importing the library that defines 'attribute', correcting the name to
>   the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
>   'attribute'.

```
  saveToPrefs(SharedPreferences prefs, Person user) {
    print('attempting to save details');
    for(String attribute in (user.toMap().keys)) {
      var testField = user.attribute;
      if(testField != null) {
        switch(runtimeType(user.attribute)) {
          case String:
            {
              prefs.setString(attribute, testField);
              break;
            }
          case double: {
            prefs.setDouble(attribute, testField);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

How do I get access to `Person user` fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, well I've found an elegant work around, use .forEach to get the Objects fields & it's keys. Seemingly Dart doesn't yet have a good elementary type query, so you just have to do it long hand with if statements.

```
    saveToPrefs(SharedPreferences prefs, Person user) {
    print('attempting to save details');
    (user.toMap()).forEach((key, value) {
      if(value != null) {
        if(value is String) prefs.setString(key, value);
        else if(value is List<String>) prefs.setStringList(key, value);
        else if(value is double) prefs.setDouble(key, value);
        else if(value is int) prefs.setInt(key, value);
        else if(value is bool) prefs.setBool(key, value);
      }
    });
  }
```

I'm content, hope it may assist someone.